# nested for loops in c++

Tags: python, c++

in school we only learn python and I want to learn c++ on my own. I have learned basics and now I try to solve problems from my textbook in both languages.

```
n = int(input())
b=0
c=0
for i in range (1,n+1):
    b += i
    for j in range (1,i+1):
        c += j 
print(b,c)
```

This is in python and it works perfectly but when i try to transcipt it to c++ I don't get the good result:

```
for (i=1;i<a+1;i++)
    d = d+i;
    for (n=1;n<i+1;n++)
        c = c+n;
```

(I have not transcripted whole c++ code because it is much longer than python and just inpunts and outputs so I just took the nested loop)
What am I doing wrong? please help

Comment: tell us what are you expecting it to do

Comment: You need to use {} in c++ for this since indentation means nothing. As a result only the line after the for() is part of the loop in both cases.

Comment: Have you tried using braces? (`{}`)

Comment: @NickA Is correct. Unlike with python's indentation, scope blocks must be enclosed in `{}` braces in c++. You shouldn't try to learn c++ with help of Stack Overflow, that won't work well. Use a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242) instead.

Comment: The important lesson to take from this, is that one should not learn one programming language by a simple "transcription" of another.

Comment: Thank you very much it works now. So braces are a must :)

Comment: @user9149607 _"So braces are a must :)"_ Not for one liners, but I recommend to always use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need `{}`. In C++ `{` marks the start of a body and `}` means end of body of a statement such as the `for` loop. Otherwise your `for` loop will only iterate over the next statement in line:

```
int n = 10, b = 0, c = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    b += i;
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
        c += j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ if you have a for loop it only loops the next statement and not the whole identation block after like in python. To do that you need to surround with curly braces. Like this:

```
for (i=1;i<a+1;i++)
{
    d = d+i;
    for (n=1;n<i+1;n++)
        c = c+n;
}
```

Otherwise your code is equivalent to this: (in C++ identation means nothing)

```
for (i=1;i<a+1;i++)
    d = d+i;
for (n=1;n<i+1;n++)
    c = c+n;
```